# What are you supposed to write inside addOnCompleteListener?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm currently trying to use firebase remote in my android project by following [docs][1] and I'm at the point where I have to fetch my values but it keeps giving me an error when I'm literally copy pasting the code from the docs (see code below). It keeps saying "cannot resolve method addOnCompleteListener" but since I don't really understand what's supposed to be written inside the function, I can't seem to fix the problem.

```
private void fetchConfig() {
      mFirebaseRemoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Boolean> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        boolean updated = task.getResult();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Config params updated: " + updated);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch and activate succeeded",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fetch failed",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    displayWelcomeMessage();
                }
            });
}
```

Also I'm currently using these dependencies in my build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
```

I don't really know what versions I have to take for these dependencies, because I'm working with quite a low API level. It's for a school assignment which had a requirement that said min api 16 so that's what I picked when creating the project. But anyway does someone know what the problem could be? Or can someone explain me what this part is supposed to do for my firebase config?

Comment: Posting images is not a good practice: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is the code above inside an anonymous class?

Comment: @PeterHaddad The error says: Cannot resolve method 'addOnCompleteListener(com.example.marvelapp.config.FirebaseConfig, anonymous com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener<java.lang.Boolean>' and I think this "new onCompleteListener ..." is the only anonymous part

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the problem is with the Firebase implementation version, try changing to this versions.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'
```

Comment: Do they work with minsdk set to 16? Anyway still the same error unfortunately, so not even possible to try and build